# JAVA | Grouping only non-null values of 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

In JAVA, I’ve a two dimensional array as below:

```
sl_no    plan_names     Column3    Column4     Column5    Column6
1        abc            product1            
2        stu                
3        vwx                
4        yza            product2            
5        bcd                
6        efg                
7        nop                
8        qrs            product3               product4    product5
9        tuv
```

Now, want to list in a separate array with only non-null values of products  as below:

```
sl_no    plan_names     products
1        abc            product1
2        yza            poduct2
3        qrs            product3
4        qrs            product4
5        qrs            product5
```

It will be really helpful for me, if someone guide me on how I can achieve this.

Thank You,
Praveen

Comment: Any try from your side apart from posting here ?

Comment: @P.K.S Why are you using a 2D array to store different things (plan_names, columnX)? Are you allowed to use classes and objects?

Comment: @P.K.S See my working solution below.

Comment: @Suresh Atta,

Please find below my code :

`DataArray=new String[totalRows][3];int k=0;DataArray[0][0]="sl_no";DataArray[0][1]="plan_names";DataArray[0][2]="products";for(int i=1;i<totalRows;i++)
{for(int j=2;j<totalColumns;j++)
{if((B2BPlans_excelData[i][j]!=null)&&!B2BPlans_excelData[i][j].isEmpty()&&(!B2BPlans_excelData[i][j].equals(" ")))
{++k;DataArray[k][0]=Integer.toString(k);DataArray[k][1]=B2BPlans_excelData[i][1];DataArray[k][2]=B2BPlans_excelData[i][j];}}}`

Comment: The issue encountering here is, new array’s 1st dimension is derived from Original array’s 1st dimension – here it is totalRows. Once the records are filtered and listed in the new array, remaining records (out of totalRows) are updated with “null” as below.

`sl_no    plan_names     products
1        abc            product1
2        yza            poduct2
3        qrs            product3
4        qrs            product4
5        qrs            product5
null null null
null null null
null null null
null null null`

Comment: Don’t want to save this null values on the new array – however, new arrays 1st dimensions is based upon the Original arrays total records.

Comment: Got it. Every time I added a value to the array, I increased the counter, and trimmed the array according to the counter. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have used the object oriented approach by storing various columns of data into an object and create an array of objects instead of using 2D array to store data of various types.

**OUTPUT:**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
s_no      plan_names     Column3        Column4        Column5        
1         abc            product1       null           null           
2         stu            null           null           null           
3         vwx            null           null           null           
4         yza            product2       null           null           
5         bcd            product3       null           product4       

--------------------------------------------------------------
s_no      plan_names     Column3        Column4        Column5        
1         abc            product1       null           null           
2         yza            product2       null           null           
3         bcd            product3       null           product4       
4         bcd            product3       null           product4
```

Creating a class to store `Plan`

```
class Plan
{
    private String planName;
    private String[] columns;

    public Plan(String planName){
        this.planName = planName;
        columns = new String[3];
    }

    public boolean allColumnIsNull(){
        for(String s : columns)
            if(s != null)
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public void setColumn(String val, int colNum){
        if(colNum >= 0 && colNum < columns.length)
            columns[colNum] = val;
    }

    public String[] getColumns(){
        return columns;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return  (String.format("%-15s", planName) + String.format("%-15s", columns[0]) + 
                 String.format("%-15s", columns[1]) + String.format("%-15s", columns[2]));  
    }
}
```

With the above class, it is now easy to add/remove/read data. A method to create dummy datasets:

```
public static Plan[] createDummyData(){
    String[] names = {"abc", "stu", "vwx", "yza", "bcd"};
    Plan[] p = new Plan[5];

    for(int x=0; x<p.length; x++)
        p[x] = new Plan(names[x]);

    p[0].setColumn("product1", 0);
    p[3].setColumn("product2", 0);
    p[4].setColumn("product3", 0);
    p[4].setColumn("product4", 2);      
    return p;       
}
```

Now, in the main method, just call the methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Plan[] p = createDummyData();

    //Display All Data
    displayAllData(p);

    //Display non-null data
    ArrayList<Plan> list = getNonEmptyPlans(p);
    Plan[] p2 = list.toArray(new Plan[list.size()]);        
    displayAllData(p2);                                             
}
```

Finally some methods to do printing data collection

```
public static void displayAllData(Plan[] plans){
    int s_no = 1;
    System.out.println("\n----------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(String.format("%-10s", "s_no") + String.format("%-15s", "plan_names") + String.format("%-15s", "Column3") + 
                        String.format("%-15s", "Column4") + String.format("%-15s", "Column5"));
    for(Plan p : plans){
        System.out.print(String.format("%-10s", s_no++));
        System.out.println(p);
    }

}
```

Method to retrieve non-null data:

```
public static ArrayList<Plan> getNonEmptyPlans(Plan[] plans){
    ArrayList<Plan> list = new ArrayList<Plan>();
    for(Plan p : plans)
        if(!p.allColumnIsNull())
            for(String s : p.getColumns())
                if(s != null)
                    list.add(p);
    return list;                    
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, will give a try and confirm

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
    // Original Array which stores all data
    String arr_original[][] = new String[9][6];

    // Array where you have to copy
    String arr2[][] = new String[4][3];

    // Separate index for second array as you don't want null values
    // This index will increment only when product != null
    int row2 = 0;

    // To store Product Name of each row of original Array
    String product = "";

    // Iterate through all the rows of original array
    for (int row = 0; row <= arr_original.length; row++) {

        // Now we need to assign the entry in second array only when product
        // is not null

        // Check if products != NULL
        if (arr_original[row][2] != null 
                || arr_original[row][3] != null
                || arr_original[row][4] != null
                || arr_original[row][5] != null) {

            // Assign first 2 columns to second table
            arr2[row2][0] = arr_original[row][0];
            arr2[row2][1] = arr_original[row][1];

            // Find the product from the other 4 columns
            for (int col = 2; col <= 5; col++) {
                if (arr_original[row][col] != null) {
                    // if product != null, assign this product
                    product = arr_original[row][col];

                    // Since NOT null product is found, break the loop
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Assign product to 3rd column
            arr2[row2][2] = product;
            row2++;
        }
    }
```

Change the size of array accordingly.

Comment: @Anandh, thanks! I too derived my code somewhat similar to yours!

But, when we use [arr_original.lengt], getting unexpected null values on the new array as below.

    `sl_no    plan_names     products
    1        abc            product1
    2        yza            poduct2
    3        qrs            product3
    4        qrs            product4
    5        qrs            product5
    null null null
    null null null
    null null null
    null null null`